# Output values in query string part of Html.ActionLink()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want use the Html.ActionLink which allows passing route values for name/value pairs used in the query string with a name that defined by a variable.

```
@{
    var searchFieldName = ViewData["SearchFieldName"];
    var searchFieldValue = ViewData["SearchFieldValue"];
    string searchView = ViewData["ReturnSearchView"].ToString();
}


@Html.ActionLink("Search", searchView, new { searchFieldName = searchFieldValue });
```

I want searchFieldName to replaced with it's value, such as:

```
<a href="/search?somefield=value">
```

Instead the query string has "searchFieldName" as the name:

```
<a href="/search?searchFieldName=value">
```

How do I achieve the desired result?

Comment: the "somefield" part changes, that is why I want to use a variable.

Comment: Is `somefield` part of your route?

Comment: no, just the name of a param passed to the action.

Comment: this is being used in a partial view, which is reused in many spots, so it has be flexible enough to change the action name and param name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`@Html.ActionLink()` overload accepting a `RouteValueDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504988(v=vs.118).aspx), so you can specify the name of the key using a string:

```
@{
    var searchFieldName = ViewData["SearchFieldName"];
    var searchFieldValue = ViewData["SearchFieldValue"];

    var routeValues = new RouteValueDictionary();
    routeValues.Add(searchFieldName, searchFieldValue);

    string searchView = ViewData["ReturnSearchView"].ToString();
}

@Html.ActionLink("Search", searchView, routeValues, null);
```